# How to separate two classes when the features values predicting them are so similar ?

Tags: classification, pca, data-transformation, finance, noise

[image: The plot of the two classes plotted as a scatter plot with the top two principal components. All bi-variate plots look similar]

What should be my approach. I got 13 principal components from 21 numerical features. The 13 features have a gaussian distribution. The plot below is between the top two components. Should I clean the data since it seems very noisy. What can be done ?

Comment: Did you try at least training your model and evaluate it? Maybe the PCs together can help a lot. Of course you may also just discard the PCs and not use PCA. If you use the RBF kernel possibly it can perform well if you tune the parameters. Try using k-nearest neighbour?

Comment: Yes, I tried the following GMM or LDA performed the best followed by naive  Bayes. Tree based models aren't good enough including RF and GBM. Is there a way to get the output of K-nearest as probabilities, as those are my deliverables. I compared the performance with and without PCA, with PCA was better. I'm cutting off at 95% variance(13 in this case)